# Reload page onSubmit in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I want my React.js page to reload after hitting the submit button. This is because I put new entries into my database and once submitting was successful, I want to request new data from the database and display them.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const Questionnaire = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({questions: []});
    const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false); // approach 1
    // let updated = false // approach 2

    const onSubmit = async (answeredQuestions) => {
        let data = Object.values(answeredQuestions)
        
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', data)
            .then(response => {
                // setUpdated(false); // approach 1
                // updated = !updated; // approach 2
            }
        );
    };

    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', {})
            .then((response) => {
                setQuestions({"questions": response.data});
                setUpdated(true); // approach 1
            });
    }, [updated]);

    return (
        <> 
            <Questions questions={questions} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
        </>
    );
}

export default Questionnaire;
```

I want the `useEffect()` to be executed immediately after getting the response from `axios.put()` so that the new questions can be requested and displayed to the user.
I tried out two approaches, but either `axios.get()` was executed twice or the re-render didn't work properly.

I appreciate your support!

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.reload();` after put/post request is finished as below

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const Questionnaire = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({questions: []});
    const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false); // approach 1
    // let updated = false // approach 2

    const onSubmit = async (answeredQuestions) => {
        let data = Object.values(answeredQuestions)
        
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', data)
            .then(response => {
                //The below line will force browser refresh
                location.reload();
            }
        );
    };
....
//the rest of the codes
```

Comment: The problem with `location.reload()` is that it resets the session-data from `useContext()` which is not intended here... Still thank you for your suggestion, in most of the cases it may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer.

It seems that your logic for approach 1 is not completely correct. Try this instead

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const Questionnaire = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({questions: []});
    const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(true); // Set to true to trigger get on first render

    const onSubmit = async (answeredQuestions) => {
        let data = Object.values(answeredQuestions)
        
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', data)
            .then(response => {
                setUpdated(true); // approach 1
            }
        );
    };

    useEffect( () => {
        if (updated) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', {})
                .then((response) => {
                    setQuestions({"questions": response.data});
                    setUpdated(false); // approach 1
                });
        }
    }, [updated]);

    return (
        <> 
            <Questions questions={questions} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
        </>
    );
}

export default Questionnaire;
```

---

Old answer:

Is there any reason why you need to get data in a `useEffect`? Or could you simply do the get-request whenever the put is resolved?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const Questionnaire = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({questions: []});

    const onSubmit = async (answeredQuestions) => {
        let data = Object.values(answeredQuestions)
        
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', data)
            .then(response => {
                axios.get('http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/', {})
                    .then((response) => {
                        setQuestions({"questions": response.data});
                    });
            }
        );
    };

    return (
        <> 
            <Questions questions={questions} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
        </>
    );
}

export default Questionnaire;
```

(Or do it with async/await since you are declaring onSubmit to be an async function)

Comment: The reason why I used `useEffect()` is that I want the questions to be requested from the backend once in the beginning (before the first submit). That's why I used another `setUpdated()` inside of the call so that a re-render will happen after the questions are received.

Comment: See my updated answer. Will this work for you?

Comment: No this doesn't change anything. As far as I know `useEffect()` dependencies are triggered on variable change, and **not** based on the fact that a boolean is `true` or `false`, so there is no difference to my approach.

Comment: And an update to `update` is a variable change. The value of the variable has changed from true to false (or the opposite). I have added an if inside the `useEffect`. Is this still not working for you? What specifically is not working right now?

Comment: This is exactly the weird thing. I was wondering as well, why the variable change did not cause a re-render. And sorry, I didn't see the if-statement inside the `useEffect()`. But it doesn't affect the result, because the `useEffect()` hook is not even triggered a second time. However, I've found a workaround. I use the `<Redirect />`-component to redirect to another page which will redirect it back to the Questionnaire component. At least this causes a reload of the page, even if it's not a beautiful solution.

Comment: Strange! It works for me (just triggering the `useEffect` as I understand it should happen). But as long you have found a solution thats good! If you want me to look at it further, please make a codesandbox that replicates the problem with some mock APIs.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your support!